# Replace and delete part of a cell text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that was exported from some software... it uses code that it understands, which makes sense, but the problem is that the output isn't always best for us humans for a quick visual. Especially when a person isn't accustomed to actually reading it.

Proof in point:

This is in cell column H:

```
2020-04-01T11:28:18+00:00
```

Now, I could create an excel formula that replaces every instance manually, but what I want to do is make is to that the T and everything right of is goes the way of the dodo.

I know that there is a substitute command in Excel, but it only would do the first, I forget if there is a way to actually make it so that it will ignore the text to the right, and just take it from the T to 14 steps right and delete it so that all that is left is the Year, day and month. I will use Excel VBA if need be, but I'd rather it be a formula if possible that I can use for a copy and paste in another sheet for readable output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **H1**, in **I1** enter:

```
=Left(H1,10)
```

You don't need to locate the ***T*** because its position is fixed.

Comment: Would this remove everything right of the 10 spot then?

Comment: @MattRidge  Yes....................................try it out...............................

Comment: I was asking because I was trying to remember my old excel days... (10+ years ago) It wasn't meant to be a wiseass.